# Package is not found in the following primary source

Tags: .net, azure-devops, nuget-package

I have a build pipeline set up to create Nuget packages and publish them to a feed in artifacts.

I was able to use the feed successfully.

However when I ran the pipeline again, causing the packages to publish again I am not able to update the consuming project successfully.

Even though I can see the correct new version number in the Package Manager (Visual Studio -> Tools-> Nuget Package Manager -> Manage Nuget Packages for solution)

When I click install I get an error

```
Package '<mypackagename with version number>' is not found in the following primary source

<correct feed nuget/v3/index.json> Please verify all your online package sources are available (OR) package id, version are specified correctly.
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

I waited another 5 minutes and the problem went away. Maybe the version shows before the publishing is complete.

Comment: Just had the same time delay on our private NuGet feed hosted on Azure DevOps.  Took 10 minutes for the package to show up.

Comment: INDEED! THIS IS A REALLY OBNOXIOUS THING! 

The OP states they can see the updated version in their 'Package Manager Console' - but I think they mean the 'Nuget Package Manager' browsing UI. 

I too can see my updated package listed there but then when I attempt to run the `Install-Package` command it fails.

Comment: Thanks, It has been a while since this bothered me, but I think you must be right. I corrected the question.  ( What does OP stand for? )

Comment: I'm afraid that 5 min is very optimistic. I've uploaded the package 8 minutes ago using release pipeline but it is still `invisible` by the VS. The strange thing is that `https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/orgid/_packaging/feedguid/nuget/v3/query2/` show correct version for my package. Do you know how can I adjust the time required to refresh the package ?

Comment: @Kirsten: OP stands for Original Poster

Answer (score 213):

This is caused by caching.  If you don't want to wait like the above answer suggested, just clear Nuget caches by going to Tools -> Options -> Nuget -> General and click on the "Clear All Nuget Cache(s)" button.

Comment: For those who dont want to wait, this is the fix.

Comment: I don't understand why are they even caching because it definitely isn't working since it takes 10-15 seconds anyway for that error to appear

Comment: Worked for me.  Why is Nuget so full of these idiosyncracies and gotchas?

Answer (score 9):

After 4 hours struggle I found solution here
https://www.grapecity.com/componentone/docs/uwp/online-getting-started/config-nugetpackage.html

Tools > Options > NuGet Package Manager > Package Sources. > Click add button and add following one by one...

nuget.org
https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/

GrapeCity
http://nuget.grapecity.com/nuget
[image: reference Image]

Comment: Nuget online repo link was missing. Thank you!

Answer (score 8):

You have to check your package source I think the default is

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Offline Packages
```

So, you can change that to "All".

[image: package source]

Answer (score 3):

For Visual Studio 2022 users, close Visual Studio, open Run window, and enter in "%appdata%\NuGet".  Delete all items in that folder.  Re-open Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I did not include the url from nuget.org in the Package Source. Therefore add the url from nuget.org in "Tools-> Options-> NuGet Package Manager-> Package Sources" and the whole thing started to work. for more details can visit [this blog](https://www.agungpanduan.com/2020/05/solusi-kumpulan-error-visual-studio-asp-net-mvc.html)

Answer (score 0):

In my case there was a private network folderbased nuget repository listed in my sources. And at the moment it was not available. I unchecked it in "Tools->Options->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources" and the whole thing started to work

Answer (score -2):

Restarting Visual Studio 2019 Community fixed the issue for me.