# why did not launch windows application

Tags: windows, flutter

**i find this error when i try to run my application on windows **

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Windows in debug mode...
    Building Windows application...
    Nuget.exe not found, trying to download or use cached version.
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: The command "setlocal [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\CMake\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -DBUILD_TYPE=Debug -P cmake_install.cmake [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :cmEnd [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: :cmEnd [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: endlocal & call :cmErrorLevel %errorlevel% & goto :cmDone [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: :cmErrorLevel [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: exit /b %1 [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: :cmDone [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: if %errorlevel% neq 0 goto :VCEnd [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v170\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(157,5): error MSB3073: :VCEnd" exited with code 1. [D:\fluttr_project\downloader\build\windows\INSTALL.vcxproj]
    Exception: Build process failed.
```

------------------------------ flutter docotor ---------------------------------------

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.10.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22000.613], locale en-US)
[!] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 32.1.0-rc1)
    X cmdline-tools component is missing
      Run `path/to/sdkmanager --install "cmdline-tools;latest"`
      See https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line for more details.
    X Android license status unknown.
      Run `flutter doctor --android-licenses` to accept the SDK licenses.
      See https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/windows#android-setup for more details.
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[√] Visual Studio - develop for Windows (Visual Studio Enterprise 2022 17.1.4)
[√] Android Studio (version 4.1)
[√] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.3)
[√] VS Code (version 1.66.2)
[√] Connected device (3 available)
[√] HTTP Host Availability

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

Comment: I am facing the same error. Did you fix it and if so how?

Answer (score 0):

I found a fix for that recently:

In Visual Studio go to Tools -> Options -> Nuget -> General and click on the "Clear All Nuget Cache(s)" button.

Mentioned here: [Package is not found in the following primary source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54738695/package-is-not-found-in-the-following-primary-source/56997170#56997170)

Answer (score -1):

Update visual studio and down load nuget Package manager in it. then restart your pc.